# Throw an exception in promise catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have promise chaining in the code, when promise return with reject from another promise method and try to pass the reject to calling promise method, it throws the exception as follow and doesn't return reject promise.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Why did you create `Promise`, when `checkAuthorization` is already returns a promise?

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words ... except pictures of code - surely you could post your code in the question :p

Comment: Reason is, it is a class function, calling function waiting for the result.

Comment: that is no reason to wrap a function that returns a Promise inside a Promise constructor - that's a classic anti-pattern

Comment: here's your `Authorize` function as it should be written `Authorization.prototype.Authorize = function(data) {
    return CheckAuthorization(data).then(response => ({status: HttpStatusCode.OK, body: "Authori....", data}));
};`

Comment: `new Promise` is *not* promise chaining